# What does it mean to reach a stable point during the execution of a job?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, jobs

Trying to use `sp_stop_job` to stop a simple job that inserts data on a table when 100 rows were inserted I got confused to see the table end up with more than 100 rows every time.
Under the [Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-stop-job-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#remarks) section of the `sp_stop_job` doc it says:

> **sp_stop_job** sends a stop signal to the database. Some processes can be stopped immediately and some must reach a stable point (or an
> entry point to the code path) before they can stop.

I don't understand what it means to *reach a stable point (or an entry point to the code path)* and I believe the job keeps inserting the data on the table because it is still reaching that stable point.

---

**The code:**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[myStopJobTable](
    [id] [int] NULL,
    [nome] [varchar](50) NULL
);
```

I created a job with a step to execute the following code:

```
WHILE (1=1)
BEGIN  

    INSERT INTO MyLab.dbo.myStopJobTable
    VALUES (1, 'Some Name');

    IF ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM myStopJobTable) = 100)
    BEGIN
        EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_stop_job N'JobToBeStopped';
    END

END;
```

From that sample code I expected the job to stop before the row 101 is inserted, but it doesn't. By adding a `BREAK` inside the `IF` block the process is stopped before the insertion of row 101 happens, but in that case it's not the `sp_stop_job` working.

---

I don't want a fix for the job, what I seek is to understand that *stable point (or an entry point to the code path)*. What does it mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The job is not waiting to "reach a stable point". The key point is:

> sp_stop_job sends a stop signal to the database.

`sp_stop_job` sends the stop request SQL Server Agent but does not wait for it to complete. The T-SQL script continues while SQL Server Agent processes the stop request asynchronously. The  additional rows inserted after `sp_stop_job` was executed reflect the time between receipt of the stop request until SQL Server Agent got around to cancelling it. This typically takes a few milliseconds or more depending on overall activity.

The note about "reach a stable point" in the context of a T-SQL job step is the same as any query cancel request. It includes the time the database engine needs to release resources and rollback the transaction. That time is insignificant with the singleton insert in your example but would be more noticeable had the cancelled script done more work, like inserted millions of rows in a single transaction.

Comment: Thanks, Dan Guzman. I didn't expect the SQL Server Agent to take that long (time enough to insert more rows on the table) to respond to the stop signal. I noticed the problem on an instance on my desktop, so SQL Server wasn't busy to justify the delay.

Comment: @Ronaldo, the insert script is running in a tight loop so the number of rows inserted before the script actually stops can be significant if you have a fast machine and storage. On my workstation (high-end processor and SSD storage), over 200 rows were inserted between the `sp_stop_job` and the `attention` signal to cancel the script. I saw no additional rows after adding `WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:00.100';` after `sp_stop_job`.